# Unusual usage of "do" in "do you follow your path", in a sentence that is not a question

Tags: do-support

I don't understand the structure of this sentence:

> “Well, well, Inspector,” said he. “**Do** you follow your path and I will 
>   follow mine.

It is from *The Adventure of Wisteria Lodge*, part 2, a Sherlock Holmes short story.

Why is there a "do" there? shouldn't it be "you follow", or "you do follow"?

Comment: It's just an archaic/poetic construction, inverting *You do [something]*. As in Shakespeare's [Julius Caesar Act 1, Scene 2](http://www.online-literature.com/shakespeare/julius_caesar/3/) *But, look you, Cassius, The angry spot doth glow on Caesar's brow*.

Comment: And the construction functions as an imperative, both in the OP's example and in the example from Shakespeare. (Where, incidentally, is your example from, Ulukam?)

Comment: it is from "The Adventure of Wisteria Lodge - part 2", a Sherlock Holmes short story.

Comment: Aha! Even more recent than Trollope then (Cerberus's answer).

Comment: @Barrie: Yeah, actually I'd not be very surprised myself to see it in a modern novel, archaic though it may sound now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common construction in older English. It is an imperative, and I believe *do* used to be required (or very common) when the subject (= "you") of an imperative is expressed; constructions like *you tell me!* (with omitted *do*) sound modern to my ear, and often informal. I know it was at least still common in late-19th-century literature (Trollope's *The Way We Live Now*, for example).

Comment: I suspect that overall, the most prevalent constructions omit both **do** *and* **you**, in such imperatives as, for example, *"[Do] [you] listen to me!"*

Comment: @Fumble: Oh, absolutely. I meant to say that *do* was prevalent when the subject is expressed.

Comment: All permutations do/did occur, but I think it's safe to say that including *both* "do" and "you" is invariably archaic/poetic today. But we often use just one, as in *"Do listen to me!"*, and *"You listen to me!"*, which both sound totally normal to me.

Comment: @Fumble: Yeah, but *do listen to me!* sounds emphatic, whereas *do you listen to me!* in older English does not—or does it? I'd say it doesn't.

Comment: Hmm. It's hard to say because we *don't* speak like that now. I agreed with you as I read the words, but the more I think about it, the more it feels to me that "do" has always added emphasis. Adding "but" as well things gets positively desperate - [Do but listen to me](http://www.bookrags.com/ebooks/5274/130.html)

Comment: @Fumble: Hmm it's complicated. I suppose expressing the subject always adds some emphasis of its own: *listen to me* v. *you listen to me* — the latter is already more emphatic, though this is (at least partly) connected with the contrast *you–me*. So perhaps it is hard to tell whether *do* adds any more emphasis to that already present in *you* in *do you send her a letter tomorrow*. The function of *but* would be an interesting question of its own!